# EF Core 2.2: migrating starts reporting that there are pending model changes for a context

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

Existing ASP.NET Core 2.1 app (running against netcore2.1) was migrated to ASP.NET Core 2.2 (installed the sdk and changed the target). Now, whenever I ran the app, it starts showing the traditional "There are pending model changes for ApplicationDbContext".

If I follow the instructions and try to add a migration, I've noticed that it does in fact generate a new migration file. By running a diff, I can see that it's adding these lines to the Application context snapshot:

```
modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.0-rtm-35687")
```

And it will also add the following to my entity:

```
b.Property<long?>("UserServiceId1");
b.Property<long?>("UserServiceServiceId");
b.Property<long?>("UserServiceUserId");
```

I'm not sure on where it gets the UserServiceId1 name (the entity has a UserServiceId property). Btw, here's the entity class code:

```
[Table("UserIdentifiers", Schema = "Gov")]
public class UserIdentifiers
{
    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long ServiceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long UserServiceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long IdentifierId { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public long UserIdentifierId { get; set; }

    public virtual Identifiers Identifier { get; set; }
    public virtual UserServices UserService { get; set; }
}
```

The table that maps to this entity has a composite key built from the the UserId, ServiceId, UserServiceId, IdentifierId and UserIdentifierId. The snapshot has it defined like this:

```
b.HasKey("UserId", "ServiceId", "UserServiceId", "IdentifierId", "UserIdentifierId");
```

Oh, and yes, there are also migration files for dropping the UserServiceId column and adding the "new" UserServiceId1 column.

I'm not really an EF expert, so  I'm not sure on why this stopped working after migrating from 2.1 to 2.2.

So, can anyone point me in the right direction?

btw, is there a way to disable migrations on ef core?

thanks

EDIT: adding the classes referenced by the `UserIdentifiers` entity (only showing the relations between classes):

```
// identifiers

[Table("Identifiers", Schema = "Gov")]
public class Identifiers
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public long IdentifierId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IdentityResourceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ServiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Services Service { get; set; }
}

//Services
[Table("Services", Schema = "Gov")]
public class Services
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public long ServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Identifiers> Identifiers { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserServices> UserServices { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ClientServices> ClientServices { get; set; }

}

// userservices
[Table("UserServices", Schema = "Gov")]
public class UserServices
{
    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long ServiceId { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public long UserServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserIdentifiers> UserIdentifiers { get; set; }
    public virtual Services Service { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, here's the configuration performed inside the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
builder.Entity<Identifiers>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.ServiceId, x.IdentifierId });
builder.Entity<UserIdentifiers>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.ServiceId, x.UserServiceId, x.IdentifierId, x.UserIdentifierId });
builder.Entity<UserServices>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.ServiceId, x.UserServiceId });
builder.Entity<ClientServices>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.ServiceId, x.ClientId, x.ClientServiceId });
```

Comment: If there is no important data then delete the database and all migrations too. Then generate a brand new migration and update database!

Comment: can you share your one to many relationship for the UserIdentifiers Entity?

Comment: @Simonare can you be more specific? what relationship are you after?

Comment: dbContext configuration which holds your entity relationship between UserIdentifier and UserService entities

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for the quick reply. I've added the classes with the data annotations...not sure if that is what you're looking for (sorry, EF newbie :()

Comment: Try to run `Update-Database -Script` command to get the `SQL script`, and then run them part by part to check whether you will get any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine solve it by adding the "missing" foreignkey info to the model:

```
[ForeignKey("ServiceId, IdentifierId")]
public virtual Identifiers Identifier { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId, ServiceId, UserServiceId")]
public virtual UserServices UserService { get; set; }
```

And now everything works out as expected.

thanks again